# Wicket - Double redirect

Tags: java, wicket

Just a little question.
How can I implements a double redirect between three page?

Es.

```
    public class A extends BasePage{

    public A() {
        super("A");
        setResponsePage(new B());
    }

}

public class B extends BasePage{

    public B() {
        super("B");
        setResponsePage(new C());
    }

}
```

Wicket just stop at Page B without redirect to page C.

Don't ask why I have to do this this. I only need to know if is possibile even not using setResponsePage.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334827/wicket-how-to-redirect-to-another-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wicket will use the last executed setResponsePage() to determine its redirect-page. In your case, that's setResponsePage(new B()) and not setResponsePage(new C()). Indeed, the latter is executed while constructing B.

If you would do

```
public class A extends BasePage{

    public A() {
        super("A");
        B pageB = new B();
        setResponsePage(pageB);
        pageB.init();
    }

}

public class B extends BasePage{

    public B() {
        super("B");
    }

    public init() {
        setResponsePage(new C());
    }

}
```

it should work, and you would get a redirect to C!

Comment: It works very well but I have a question.
Wich page flow wins? What happen to page B?

Comment: Nothing really 'happens' to page B. It just gets created, like C. Because C is the page that Wicket will return to the browser, C is also rendered, and page B is not..!